# RestKit 0.10.2: unknown type name RKFetchedResultsTableController

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I am using the current master branch of RestKit on Github (0.10.2) if that matters.

I already do `#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>` in my table view controller class. I even go further with `#import "RestKit/Code/UI/RKFetchedResultsTableController.h"`. But I got error message

`unknown type name RKFetchedResultsTableController`.

I thought it would be some mysterious bug of Xcode. So I delete derived data from organizer, restart Xcode and build again. Yet the same error message pops up again.

Need a quick fix, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now. Simply

```
#import <RestKit/UI.h>
```

fix the problem. Don't know why UI.h is not included in RestKit.h though, which is weird.